# sql function not retrieving table and giving error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-function

I have written following function in SQLServer 2005

Following is the function:

```
create function fnBillParticulars()
return table
as
return (select * from billParticulars where Id='2425')
go
```

**Its giving me following errors:**

```
1.Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnBillParticulars, Line 2
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'return'.

2.Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnBillParticulars, Line 4
  A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
```

what can be the mistake?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
create function fnBillParticulars()
returns table
as
return (select * from billParticulars where Id='2425')
go
```

Comment: Thank you. , was unware about 'returns'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can alternatively create a `VIEW` on this,

```
CREATE VIEW fnBillParticulars
AS
select * 
from billParticulars 
where where Id='2425'
```

or if you want `table valued function`

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnBillParticulars()
RETURNS @BillParticulars TABLE 
(
   Id       int,
   -- other columns here
) 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @BillParticulars (Id, ...) -- specify columns here
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    billParticulars 
    WHERE   Id = '2425';

   RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: I know views, but Team Leader told me to get aquented with functions in SQL. Thanks for answer.

Comment: ohh, good, complecated, but came to know new things in function. Thanks

Comment: yeah. This was my first attempt for functions, will go for parameters now.

Answer (score 1):

U written "where" Twice in the query.

query should be:

```
select * from billParticulars where Id='2425'
```

and use  "returns" table

```
create function fnBillParticulars()
returns table
as
return (select * from billParticulars where Id='2425')
go
```

Comment: Tayade dada, where chukun donada ithe type zalay, aani thank you, returns sathi.